# Show the encryption method used on a Zip file in Linux?

Tags: linux, encryption, zip

I’d like to see what encryption method was used on a Zip file on Linux. How can I do this?

See the following posts for reference:

- This question which shows the need to verify the encryption: [7-zip files on Linux with AES-256 encryption](https://superuser.com/q/542837/127024)
- This question for the Windows equivalent: [Show the encryption method used on a zip file in WinZip 9.0](https://superuser.com/q/334798/127024)

Answer (score 3):

Using `7za` (available in package "p7zip") with the `l` (list) function and the `-slt` (technical mode for list) switch:

```
7za l -slt my_archive.zip
```